# How to fix Matlab Solve Calculation Error/solver gives a variable back instead of a numerical answer?

Tags: matlab, solver

I'm trying to solve for q. However, this error, in the image attached, shows up and I have no clue how to fix it. The code runs smoothly without the fifth blob [k5*z5/(1+q*(k5-1))] in the equation and it solves for q. But when I add it to the equation, you get the error... Help....

z1 = 0.01188354;

z2 = 0.20291147;

z3 = 0.03386809;

z4 = 0.6087344;

z5 = 0.1426025;

k1 = 0.00211577;

k2 = 433.816504;

k3 = 0.00651267;

k4 = 12.8652437;

k5 = 3.25E-06;

syms q

eqn = k1*z1/(1+q*(k1-1)) + k2*z2/(1+q*(k2-1)) + k3*z3/(1+q*(k3-1)) + k4*z4/(1+q*(k4-1))+ k5*z5/(1+q*(k5-1)) == 1;

qvalue = solve(eqn,q,'Real',true)

[image]

Comment: Your image doesn't show an `error` it shows a `warning`.

Comment: Ohhhh but my qvalue should spit out a numerical answer or at least five different answers since it's root of 5... However, matlab just spits qvalue = x...

Answer (score 0):

You messed a bit with `solve`. It looks like your equation doesn't have real solution and you force it with `'Real',true` It should be:

```
z1 = 0.01188354;
z2 = 0.20291147;
z3 = 0.03386809;
z4 = 0.6087344;
z5 = 0.1426025;
k1 = 0.00211577;
k2 = 433.816504;
k3 = 0.00651267;
k4 = 12.8652437;
k5 = 3.25E-06;

syms q
eqn = k1*z1/(1+q*(k1-1)) + k2*z2/(1+q*(k2-1)) + k3*z3/(1+q*(k3-1)) + k4*z4/(1+q*(k4-1))+ k5*z5/(1+q*(k5-1)) == 1;
qvalue = solve(eqn,q)
```

And the output is:

```
root(z^5 - (553951988707451897271725042874967932463648393519489496501295701298760653356885564069*z^4)/146344515065711958525050250689493211538989295698771861545387136571113311336350613504 + (877647369043978904163970290106419962713606423192038983322127636310825879207936*z^3)/164487327751721471763565140886077743965784030575734255347857322244873703346919 - (3796080934806054258394941458065140559250786119491250988496078448019381612969984*z^2)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + (838076006172751803233223399262272123114675605549658858976242221943722830987264*z)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + 21452770321210561747759866301918995558818778263453224281332504760441104236544/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433, z, 1)
root(z^5 - (553951988707451897271725042874967932463648393519489496501295701298760653356885564069*z^4)/146344515065711958525050250689493211538989295698771861545387136571113311336350613504 + (877647369043978904163970290106419962713606423192038983322127636310825879207936*z^3)/164487327751721471763565140886077743965784030575734255347857322244873703346919 - (3796080934806054258394941458065140559250786119491250988496078448019381612969984*z^2)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + (838076006172751803233223399262272123114675605549658858976242221943722830987264*z)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + 21452770321210561747759866301918995558818778263453224281332504760441104236544/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433, z, 2)
root(z^5 - (553951988707451897271725042874967932463648393519489496501295701298760653356885564069*z^4)/146344515065711958525050250689493211538989295698771861545387136571113311336350613504 + (877647369043978904163970290106419962713606423192038983322127636310825879207936*z^3)/164487327751721471763565140886077743965784030575734255347857322244873703346919 - (3796080934806054258394941458065140559250786119491250988496078448019381612969984*z^2)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + (838076006172751803233223399262272123114675605549658858976242221943722830987264*z)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + 21452770321210561747759866301918995558818778263453224281332504760441104236544/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433, z, 3)
root(z^5 - (553951988707451897271725042874967932463648393519489496501295701298760653356885564069*z^4)/146344515065711958525050250689493211538989295698771861545387136571113311336350613504 + (877647369043978904163970290106419962713606423192038983322127636310825879207936*z^3)/164487327751721471763565140886077743965784030575734255347857322244873703346919 - (3796080934806054258394941458065140559250786119491250988496078448019381612969984*z^2)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + (838076006172751803233223399262272123114675605549658858976242221943722830987264*z)/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433 + 21452770321210561747759866301918995558818778263453224281332504760441104236544/1151411294262050302344955986202544207760488214030139787435001255714115923428433, z, 4)
root(z^5 - (553951988707451897271725042874967932463648393519489496501295701298760653356885564069*z^4)
```